# How to Store alert messages in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I plan on creating a Facebook style alerts system and I am wonder what is the best way to store the alerts. What kind of table should I use?

This is what I was thinking:

```
   CREATE TABLE `alerts`(
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   status enum('active','inactive','deleted') DEFAULT active,
   user_id INT NOT NULL,
   message VARCHAR 255 NOT NULL,
   );
```

Comment: Side note: Are you sure it's a good idea to lie to your users about their alert being deleted?

Comment: How many rows do you think this alerts table may contain ? What happens if in the future you need to amend or add a status to that enum ?

Comment: @Chrisitan: The reason I do not want to physically "delete" the alerts is because I heard it messes with MySQL indexes an hurts performance. Not sure it that is true, but I can always go through and delete "status = 'deleted'" rows and re index the table.

Comment: @F00 Let me just guess that the table will contain 100,000. If I need to amend the enum status I will simple just alter the table.

Answer (score 0):

Absent any more detail, I think the most we can say is: sure, that'll work.

There is no fundamental flaw with your table schema. Be sure to include an index on (user_id) or more likely on `(user_id, status)` (since you're likely to query only active alerts most of the time), and a foreign key from `user_id` to your `user` table.

And you might consider making `message` a `TEXT` field, unless you specifically want to limit it to 255 characters.

Comment: So are you you saying that the DB should be InnoDB type since that is the only table type that supports Foreign key's?

Comment: Yes. Unless you're using fulltext indices, all tables should be InnoDB so that you can define proper foreign keys.